# How to find out whether capacitor is the fault for failed single phase motor?

Tags: capacitor, motor, induction-motor, troubleshooting, single-phase

Single phased motor rated for 220V, 50Hz isn't working. I want to know whether is it just due to a failed capacitor or is the motor itself is damaged. The capacitor looks clean from the outside; no burnt marks on it. I have a tester and a multimeter.

Here's the diagram on how motor is energised:
[image]

My idea is to check voltage between N and Y (refer image) while MCB is turned ON, if voltage is 0V (or significantly less than 220v) then Capacitor has failed, otherwise capacitor is working fine. Is this the good way to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove one lead on the capacitor. Measure its capacitance. If its value is within the tolerance of what it is marked with the capacitor is likely good and the motor stator is damaged.

Comment: I have a very basic multimeter; can measure DC voltage, DC current, AC voltage, AC current, resistance and continuity, that's all. So i cant measure capacitance.