# 0 V across motor capacitor terminals, but resistance is 20 Ω. Is the capacitor dead?

Tags: capacitor, induction-motor, troubleshooting, phase-shift, single-phase

It is a 36 μF, 440 VAC, 50 Hz rated motor running capacitor, used in a single-phase motor. AC source is 240 V, 50 Hz.

The motor has stopping working. I want to know whether it is due to a faulty capacitor.

Circuit diagram:
[image]

Observations:
**When the motor switch is OFF:**

1. The DC voltage across the capacitor (between R and Y) is 0 V (a digital multimeter shows 2 mV, which could be a reading error).
2. The resistance across it (between R and Y) is a constant 20 Ω.
3. The voltage difference between the live wire and one of the terminals of the capacitor (between P and R or between P and Y) is around 150 V (I guess it's the voltage drop across the MCB, but since the MCB is in thd off state, shouldn't it be the full 240 V?)

**When the motor switch is ON:**

1. The voltage between N and R is 240 V, and the voltage between N and Y is 240 V.
2. The voltage across the capacitor terminals (between R and Y) is 0 V. (The capacitor should cause a phase difference between R and Y by 180° right? If yes, the expected value should not be zero, right?)

Based on my observations, what I conclude is that the capacitor is shorted, because:

1. 20 Ω across it when tested while the switch is OFF and the capacitor is barely charged (2 mV)
2. The voltage between its terminals is 0 V, but it should be non-zero, indicating that the capacitor is just shorting, instead of causing a phase difference.

Am I right?

Comment: `resistance across it (between R and Y)` With the motor connected? Try to measure the capacitor on its own.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699885/how-to-find-out-whether-capacitor-is-the-fault-for-failed-single-phase-motor

Comment: Did you measure the capacitor having 20 ohms while it was connected to motor? If yes, you did not measure the capacitor, but both the motor and capacitor, so you don't know anything about the capacitor, only the combination of motor and capacitor.

Comment: @greybeard thanks, i forgot about that, i checked it beteen R and its other terminal by disconnecting it from being connected to the Y (thus disconnecting the parallelly connected motor). Now, it has (unfortunately) very high resistance (no finite reading). I guess the fault is with motor or a loose wire near motor :( . But still thinking why voltage across it while running is 0V?

Comment: If you have 240 V between P and R then the MCB is open.

Comment: @Transistor oh sorry, it was a mistake, It is between N & R and N & Y, not P. I corrected it now. thanks

Comment: If the unit is a few years old, there’s a very good chance the capacitor has failed.  The capacitor is usually not too expensive, so the simplest test is one of substitution.  You could measure the current through the capacitor - if you have a clamp meter this the quickest and simplest test. If the current is low, then either the capacitor is not doing its job or there’s problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. *Disconnect* the capacitor (and *discharge* it by shorting it for a bit, just to be sure)
2. *Measure* the capacitance. It should be the *rated capacitance within the tolerance marked on the capacitor*. If it is much less then the capacitor has failed and needs to be replaced. It's possible this also killed the motor, though. If it won't read capacitance check for a short, but that's unlikely-- they are designed to blow shorts away ("self-healing") which lowers the capacitance a bit each time that happens.

Answer (score 0):

> When motor switch is ON […] The capacitor should cause a phase difference between R and Y by 180° right?

Not quite. I expect almost 90°.

> If yes, the expected [voltage between R and Y] should not be zero, right?

Right.

Comment: en.wikipedia: [Split-phase motor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_motor#Split-phase_motor)

Comment: yes, i measured it wrong. i checked the resistance of capacitor alone, it is very high. can the 0V across R and Y while MCB is ON still explains that the capacitor is dead?